# Script declared in rc.local doesn't run after soft reboot

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and two scripts that handle the updates of an app.

1. download.sh
2. update.sh

download.sh downloads the new version of the app, prepares it for deployment and restarts the device.
Update.sh is declared in the rc.local file and runs perfectly when I do a hard reset. But nothing happens when the device is rebooted from the download.sh with the following command `shutdown -r now`

Comment: This question belongs on [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: sorry wasn't aware of its existence